# 世界の年平均気温の偏差の経年変化 meaning

Tags: translation, words

I was reading the global warming article on the Japanese wikipedia and got stuck on this phrase

> 世界の年平均気温の偏差の経年変化

I looked up the last two words individually, which lead  me to an interpretation of: 'world change [i.e. increase] of average temperature deviation over the years'. Is this correct?

I think, from what I've understood in my previous reading, temperature deviation is the difference from a baseline average temperature [pre-1950's from memory]. But as this is the first time I've encountered 偏差 and 経年変化, I'm worried I might be jumping the gun.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :-)

Edit: I found out later the baseline temperature is the 1981-2010 average, not that of 1891-1950, as I originally presumed. The caption in the article doesn't explicitly identify this average, which led to a lot of confusion on my part. It would have been helpful if the Japanese article didn't leave this information out.

Comment: It's not "pre-warming average", it is an average from a period measurements were taken (1891-2010) and a yearly deviation from this average. It's not what statistical deviation is most commonly used for, but the caption is coherent. Maybe there is a better technical term, but that's a question for CrossValidation or English.SE.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the graph uses the average before a certain date to establish a baseline average temperature, and this is used to determine a deviation of an annual average temperature after that date. My wording was clumsy. My confusion stemmed from having two similar next to each other: 偏差 and 変化.

Comment: No, it **doesn't** use the average before a certain date to show deviation values after that date. Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Comment: Among other things, I'm a maths tutor. If the average were over 1891-2010, the area above and below 0 should be equal, hence average. The Japanese article unfortunately has a vague caption; it doesn't say what the average is based on, only the period it covers (1891-2010). The graph was a pain to hunt down but I found it. On further research I found the average is based on that of 1980-2010 - the area above and below is equal based on that measurement. The Japanese article is confusing because of that missing information.

Comment: @Robert Are you really seeing [this](http://www.data.jma.go.jp/cpdinfo/temp/an_wld.html)? I think it clearly says the baseline is 1981-2010平均 (adjacent to the y-axis and also in the description).

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: "On further research I found the average is based on that of 1980-2010". That's what I mean by baseline. Though, I should have said 1981, not 1980.

Comment: I think 経年変化 is a trend which is estimated by the data. I think annual change sounds like change in time or change in deviation from previous year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [①世界]の[②年平均気温]の[③偏差]の[④経年変化]

Just reverse the order and you can get the basic literal translation:

> [④annual change] of [③the deviation] of [②the annual average temperature] of [①the world]

Technical phrases can usually be translated rather literally. I don't think "world change" is a good translation although it may mean something.

偏差 roughly means "some difference from some representative value (mean, median, mode, etc) of the population". It's often a shorter synonym for 標準偏差 ([standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)), but it can be a simple arithmetic difference from some average value. If you are seeing [this](http://www.data.jma.go.jp/cpdinfo/temp/an_wld.html), the "difference" is simple arithmetic difference, and the baseline "representative value" is "世界の年平均気温の1981〜2010年平均", the mean of the world temperature in 1981–2010.

経年変化 is just <del>"annual change"</del> "change over the years".

Comment: The last sentence spoils (effectively negates) the whole answer.

Comment: @macraf You mean 経年変化? How?

Comment: I mean "yearly shift" and "inner-annual change". It's not what the graph shows. It shows data distribution throughout/over the years. But there is no year-to-year relation.

Comment: @macraf I still don't get it. They're obviously temporal data, and the original word is not 分布 (distribution) but 変化 (change/shift), anyway.

Comment: I think annual change might be better (the graph shows how the average changes from year to year). Or perhaps, showing how the annual average temperature has changed over the entire period.

Comment: Oh, that's [**inter**-annual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interannual), not **intra**-annual nor **inner**-annual. Maybe inter-annual is not common as I thought?

Comment: Jisho has 'change over the years'. That seems perfect to me.

Comment: In other words, I agree with everything except (4). But you were probably getting at the correct meaning and the rest of the answer made sense and was helpful.

Comment: That’s the problem: seeing the data you construe an image of a change in your mind. But the data itself shows only deviation of measurements compared to a long-time average. You can’t tell if a negative value means that the average as known at that year decreased. It might be a warmest year locally (year-to-year), even historically, but still below the 119-year average.

Comment: Compare https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/gwp/temp/ann_wld.html. It's an extended form of the graph the caption was based on. It wouldn't make any sense for there to be a huge area below the average and a small one above. In that case, it wouldn't be an average. 1891-2010 is the time period of the graph, not the period the average is based on. The graph in the English wikipedia does have an average based on the 1890-2010 period, but the two graphs are not the same if you check the numbers on the vertical axis.

Comment: @Robert 1981-2010 is the baseline on which the "average" is based. It's **1981**, not **1891**. See the embedded text right below the graph. That's why the red line crosses zero at around 1995.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; sorry. Oops. It was a typo.

Comment: @macraf Hmm, maybe you mean "inter-annual" is closer to 年度間 or 前年との差分 rather than 経年, despite [what's written here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=interannual)? Here 経年 just means "at time granularity of *year*". It just says this is a yearly graph (1950, 1951, 1952, ...), not monthly (Jan 1950, Feb 1950, ...). What's the best word?

Comment: @naruto Jisho's definition change over the years fits the bill. Such a phrase implies a time scale of years, not months etc.

Comment: @Robert Oh, then what does "I agree with everything except (4)" mean?  (Well, I somehow feel I should have used "annual", which can be ambiguous but much safer...)

Comment: @naruto Sorry; I'm wrong again. I looked up interannual: Measured or evaluated on a yearly basis or from one year to the next. Given that definition, your wording works fine.

Comment: As a descendant of Latin-speaking Romans, let me just add that the whole point here is in knowing the meaning of "inter" (and "intra"). "Inter" is a prefix that means "among or between a group". If you think of "interstate highway" you get it immediately. On the other hand, "intra" is a prefix that means "inside or withing a group". Therefore, in this case "inter-years" (although I'm not sure how much is used in English) makes sense if you want to say "among a group of years" or in other words "over the years" and I believe the same holds for "inter annual".

Comment: Having studied some Latin, I find it very helpful for decoding the definition of words. But on occasion it can also be unhelpful. Take the word 'explode', for instance. The Latin etymology offers you no assistance at all. For 'interannual', the go-to reference should be the dictionary, since this is a technical word. Here we get: "Measured or evaluated on a yearly basis or from one year to the next." Which is the meaning implied by naruto's wording. I initially rejected naruto's choice of words based on similar thinking and found myself humbled by such a dictionary search.

Comment: @macraf So I asked about "inter-annual" [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145626/annual-vs-inter-annual-vs-intra-annual) and the general consensus seems to be "It may be correct, but sounds odd." Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @naruto 僕が議論の趣旨を取り違えてるか、その他何かの勘違いをしているかもしれませんが、「経年」って言うと普通は「複数の（あるいは多くの）年を経ての・通しての」という意味ですよね。「ある一つの年を経ての・通しての」という意味ではないですよね？この点については同意見でしょうか。（もし同意見ならこの質問は愚問なので忘れてください。）

Comment: @goldbrick あ、はい、それは同意見です。経年とは、「特定の1年の中での」じゃなくて「複数年にわたる」の意味だと思います。「経年劣化」も普通は5年や10年とかの話だと思います。annualはどちらの意味にも取れそうな曖昧な表現かも…と疑心暗鬼になったのですが、どうやら別にそんなことはなかったぜ、という話です…。

Comment: ならば無問題でござい！失礼しやしたっ。

Comment: @naruto No, sorry, it is not “annual change”. As I already mentioned, it is a value of deviation “over the years”. With “annual change”: a value of -0.2 indicates -0.2 change from previous year. It is not the case here. Value of -0.2 on this graph says only that in a particular year it was 0.2 below the 120-year average. There is no relation to any other year, so no “inter”, no “intra”, no “-ly”, no any other adjective indicating relation between years.

Comment: @macraf Where did "from previous year" come from? Which part of my translation had such an implication? I believe none of "inter-", "change" and "deviation" implies "from previous year" or "successive difference (a(k) - a(k-1))". (By the way, the baseline is the 30-year average of 1981-2010.)

Comment: @naruto Sorry, I already addressed that in the comment above. If you choose to ignore my words, which you are free to do, do it thoroughly and do not reply.

Comment: Oh, maybe "shift"? I used it vaguely as an alternative of "trend" or "change", but is this a word that explicitly means "difference between successive two values" in some field? (And please, you have also ignored much of the discussion here; this was the fourth time people pointed out "the baseline is 1981-2010 average")

Comment: @mackeygoo 恐らくですが、誰一人として争っていない部分の解説を一生懸命やっており、争点が何なのかを理解されていない気がします。[これ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54021/5010#comment94037_54025)を含む一連のコメントにおいて、macrafさんは、「(inter-)annual changeというのはひとつ前の年との値の差分のことだ、前の年と比べて気温が上がったか下がったかのことだ。だからこの折れ線グラフを annual change と表現したら間違いだ」と主張しているような気がします（たぶん）。私は「(inter-)annual changeとは単に値の年度毎の経時的推移のことであり、前後の年の気温と引き算をする概念ではない。だからこの折れ線グラフを annual change と呼ぶのは正しい」と思っています。まずここまで理解されていますか？ mackeygooさんはどちらのご意見ですか。

Comment: @macraf I'm sorry, perhaps I was reading your last comment wrongly. You think "annual change" is *still* incorrect to describe this graph (because "annual change" by definition means "the difference from the previous year"), right? But Robert and everyone [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/145626/8629) seem to think "annual change" is fine. Anyway, "change over the years" would be the safest choice everyone can agree...

Comment: @naruto: 日本語を勉強しているサイトですので、日本語で考えるように勧めます。使わなくても表現できるグラフの説明にたまたま使われた「経年変化」という日本語を、細かなニュアンスが分からない英語の言い回しでどれが正しいか議論するのは無駄だと思います。

Comment: @mackygoo いやだから、日本語での意味は全員わかりきっていて(グラフ見りゃわかります)、対応する英訳が適切かどうかの一点のみで揉めて‌​いて、しかもその一つの英語の誤りで話がひ‌​っくり返るくらい酷いミスだとmacrafさんに言われてるか‌​ら、こんなことになってるんですけど…。英‌​語で揉めてもしょうがないのでいちばん無難‌​そうな英語に修正したはずが、まだ違う‌​よと言われてるところです。上にあるコメントはほぼ全部経年変化の訳語に関してですが、それがどうでもいいというならmacrafさんの意見と正反対ですし、そもそも何しにここにきたんですか。

Comment: If one feels annual change sounds inappropriate , how about saying annual datas of the deviation form 1891-.

Comment: typo datas-> data.

Answer (score 0):

## English

> 世界の年平均気温の偏差の経年変化

The above phrase means as a whole "the transition of the average temperature in the world." To put it in detail, "it is a plot of the world's annual average temperature (one representative point per year) for a hundred and decades and shows the transition of the temperature as a graph."
However, since we want to see only the state of change, they don't use the real temperatures, but a graph that moves the zero point of the Y-coordinate using the appropriate average temperature value (average value of 1981-2010).
In short, "it is what makes only the change (ripple) of the temperature transition easy to see, where the unit of X-coordinate plot is year."

The words with "偏差" and "経年変化" are somewhat exaggerated and have an atmosphere of mathematical terms, but they don't have the particularly difficult meanings, which can be rewritten in easier words as mentioned above.

They already use the word "**年**平均気温" in this phrase, so they didn't need to use the word with "経**年**変化" where "年" appears again, but they used it. So I think that the respondents to this question and people who made comments were confused and a lot of comments were posted endlessly.

For the interpretation other than "経年変化", naruto seems to be correct (+1), and for "経年変化", macraf seem to be correct (+1 for the comment) from the beginning.

## 日本語

> 世界の年平均気温の偏差の経年変化

上記の意味は、
基本的には世界の平均気温の推移です。少し詳しく言うと、世界の１年間の平均気温（１年に１つの代表点）を百数十年分プロットしてグラフにして気温の推移/変化を表したもの。但し、変化の様子だけを見たいので実気温ではなく、適切な平均気温値（1981-2010の平均値）を用いて座標移動をしたグラフです。要するに気温推移の変化分（リップル）だけを見やすくしたものです。プロットの単位は年。

「偏差」とか「経年変化」という意味はなんだか大げさで数学的な匂いはしますが簡単に言い換えることができる上記のように特にむずかしい意味を持っていません。もっと簡単な普通の言葉に言い換えられそうです。

既に、「**年**平均気温」と言ってますので「年」が再び登場する「経**年**変化」という言葉を使ったので皆さんが混乱し、大量のコメントが往来しているのだと思います。

「経年変化」以外の解釈はnarutoさん（+1）、「経年変化」の理解は、macrafさん(コメントに+1)が最初から合っているように思います。

Answer (score 0):

I think probably the confusions arise from this is discrete time-intervals and they are fixing the deviation value. Therefore, I think "Annual change" which is the translation of **経年変化** sounds unfit since they are not really monitoring the phenomena all the time but just pick up the value they already collected and plot it on the sheet. However, Naruto already picking up the term "change over the years" for **経年変化**, I think it can avoid the confusion.

I think this is called Time-Series Analysis. They have data of average temperatures and have prepared deviations and want to analyse the model(ex:find a trend of the data,how much volcano eruption affects the data)

Horizontal axis is arranged for a discrete equal time intervals by 1 year measurement. Vertical axis is arranged for a deviation value calculated for each year. Then, they prepared the regression line for a trend as below.

[image]

Reference:

**長期変化傾向（トレンド）の解説**

http://www.data.jma.go.jp/cpdinfo/temp/trend.html

**CSV データ　世界の年平均気温**

http://www.data.jma.go.jp/cpdinfo/temp/list/an_wld.html

**Python Code**

import pandas as pd
import csv
import pprint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('\an_wld.csv', sep=',',header=None)
df.values
x = df[0]
y = df[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5CYf.png)
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x, y, marker = "o")
xp = np.linspace(1890, 2016, 120)
plt.plot(xp, p(xp))
plt.show()

Comment: annual change が良くないということ自体はmacrafさんと同じ意見ですが、その理由がかなり異なっているようです。macrafさんは「annual changeとは"対前年比"(ひとつ前の年との差分)のことのみを指すから」とおっしゃっているようです。

Comment: @naruto Macrafさんはannual changeを統計で前年のデータと比べて、どの程度数値が変わったか話している訳ではない、僕は気象庁が気象データを気象予報か何かの為に一年中データを集めているに聞こえるという事だと思います。まあ、robertさんが他の人が納得できると思うと言えばannual changeを使っても良いと思います。ただ僕はannual value,annual data、もしくは naruto さんの言うようにchange  over years.